# How to get the SQL Server version/ patch level from passive node?

Tags: sql-server, clustering

I needed to get the SQL Server version/ patch level from 2 node cluster's (active/ passive) passive node. And didn't find any information about that.

Answer (score 1):

One of the ways to get this information is SQL Server Configuration Manager. We need to right-click on stopped SQL Server service, go to Properties and on Advanced tab check the File Version field.

[image]

If yo know any other ways to get this information, feel free to post them as answer. Thanks.